# Trying to install a video card but I have no video so I dont understand how to use additional drivers

Tags: drivers, ssh, video

I installed a GTX 970, but I have no video so I can't see. I guess I could SSH into my machine, but I do not know how to use the "Additional Drivers" while logged in on ssh?

Comment: We currently don't know what OS/product/release you're asking about; please tell us, or are you hoping we guess correctly?   I'd expect you can still operate your machine via *text terminal*; but again we've not been given any actual useful specifics so we're currently guessing.

Comment: Try the command `sudo ubuntu-drivers install`.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu has a built-in ubuntu-drivers program that can decide automatically which proprietary graphics driver to install, and streamlines the installation of Nvidia drivers. Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers install   
sudo reboot
```

The `install` option of `ubuntu-drivers` installs drivers that are appropriate for automatic installation including their dependencies. In Ubuntu 20.04 and later running `sudo apt upgrade` not only upgrades the versions of the proprietary graphics drivers that were installed by `sudo ubuntu-drivers install`. Sometimes `sudo apt upgrade` even upgrades the proprietary graphics driver packages to more recent packages, in which case `sudo apt autoremove` removes the older packages which were replaced by the newer ones. For most users there's no reason to guess about which proprietary graphics driver to install, because if your system deserves a graphics driver upgrade it will get one.